# How to divide the DataFrames based first column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
Id Jan Feb mar apr
N1 12  23. 56. 76
   65. 08. 04. 67
N2 45. 76. 87. 34 
   45  76. 76. 65
   23. 65. 34. 87
```

This value from excel sheet I written below code

```
Import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
df.iloc[0:2]
```

This code print two rows I need to extract sometime three rows depend upon excel sheet value how to give index instead of two?

Comment: ```df.count()``` ?

Comment: Bro I need first two row as one dataframe and another three as second dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to do the `ffill` NaN

```
d = {x : y for x , y in df.groupby(df.Id.mask(df.Id.eq('')).ffill())}
```

Comment: df.Id i want pass variable df.var and first i assign value to the var=Id how to pass the id as variable?